# How to alter cassandra table columns

Tags: cassandra, cql

I need to add additional columns to a table in cassandra. But the existing table is not empty. Is there any way to update it in a simple way? Otherwise what is the best approach to add additional columns to a non empty table? thx in advance.

Comment: Do you mean add additional fields (columns) to a table? Is this a CQL question?

Comment: Yes. I need to add additional column definitions to a non empty keyspace .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a good example of adding table columns to an existing table in the CQL documentation on [ALTER](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html#reference_ds_xqq_hpc_xj__adding-a-column). The following statement will add the column `gravesite` (with type `varchar`) to to the table `addamsFamily`:

> ALTER TABLE addamsFamily ADD gravesite varchar;